# GDT versus Paging

Tags: kernel

I am trying to boot a custom kernel. QEMU is page-faulting on the address of the GDT. Why is this? I thought that after I load it using the `lgdt` instruction, the address of the GDT isn’t needed anymore. If it is still needed, how can I keep it around? (I cannot simply point a PTE at the GDT address, as I only have 2048 of those and they are all needed for pointing to the kernel code.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you sligtly misunderstand the MMU in x86.

To determine the physical address of the data, processor takes the **logical** address (the one you use when accessing memory) and a segment selector, puts it through the segmentation unit to yield a **linear** address and then maps it to a **physical** address with a paging unit if it's enabled.

Now take a look at the `lgdt` [instruction description](http://faydoc.tripod.com/cpu/lgdt.htm):

> They are the only instructions that directly load a linear address
>   (that is, not a segment-relative address) and a limit in protected
>   mode.

When paging is not enabled, a linear address is directly mapped to a physical address, so you may say that you are in a **physical** space. However, when you enable paging, Dorothy leaves Kansas: any address (except for a physical address of the page directory the CR3 register) is now in a **linear** space and goes through paging transformation.

As for your problem: it looks like you have used just two page *directory* entries. Why? Try taking another one and Bob's your uncle.

Comment: I’m sorry, but you’ve used so much programmer slang that I can’t quite understand what you are saying. Could you please edit your answer to clarify? Thanks.